Extreme Polar Ice Erosion
I want to better understand the effects of melting ice on a planet with an axial tilt more extreme than our own. I want to say the planet in question has a tilt of fifty degrees, and so either hemisphere experiences long periods in complete darkness or daylight, which leaves a slim temperate zone near the planet's equator.
Having read similar-ish questions that have been answered, I want to clarify that I'm not asking about the size of climate zones, but rather how would large areas of polar ice thawing erode the terrain once the hemispheres switch seasonal positions? Would large mountain ranges flatten out due to the ice water thawing?
Assume the planet is our Earth but with a 50° tilt, I haven't thought out an original solar system and would rather use the Earth's tectonic plates, geographic formation, orbit, and seasonal lengths. Alternatively, if the amount of time isn't enough for either hemisphere to freeze over, the planet could be moved further back in its distance from the sun.

The question could have better focus. Are you wanting to deal with glacier erosion? Title suggests glacier erosion. High axial tilt and ice albedo suggest that snowball planet is a likely scenario bringing ice sheets and glaciers. Yet the body is asking about water erosion from melting ice/snow.

Water and ice erosion happen mostly by transporting rocks which grind against the ground under the water or ice. Mild melting of ice doesn't do much erosion. Movement of kilometers thick of ice moves large boulders under the ice grinding away. Slow rain doesn't do much. An ice dam holding back cubic kilometers of water suddenly giving way scours much of eastern Washington state producing the Channel Scablands. So, your processes are critical.

The simple perspective
let's consider a water world and ignore erosion for a moment. The 50° tilt doesn't mean half the planet becomes ice, only that the polar ice caps grow to a greater extent for half the year and shrink to a greater extent the other half. Since it's halfsies both ways, there won't be a change in sea level, only a change in the encroaching and melting ice. The frozen cap at the time it starts melting will be quite a bit larger than Earth's ice caps — ignoring land. What you will have is a considerable current flowing due to the ebb-and-flow of ice melt. OK, hold that thought.
An Ode to Antarctica
The presence of land directly over the pole makes a big difference. Land gets colder than ocean. Consider the northern ice cap, which has water under it. The northern ice cap enjoys an average thickness of 2-3 meters and in some instances is 5 meters deep.
Compare this to Antarctica — a whomping big parcel of real estate just waiting for the right realtor to develop it. Antarctica is 80% the size of Russia — and the ice cap thickness is an average of 2 kilometers. Land gets colder than ocean and so the ice cap is thicker.
This means the ice cap at Earth's north pole would melt faster and recede more deeply than ever it would in the south. It also means there's a LOT more water in the south, but also that it will melt more slowly... kinda.
It's true that the colder landmass would lead to slower ice melt... but there's so much ice that I believe there would ultimately be more liquid water regardless.
OK, so on an Earth tilted 50° what erosion would we expect?

On Antarctica I wouldn't expect any. However, over geological periods of time, it might mean that Antarctica isn't as depressed as it is today. But ultimately, I believe no erosion.

Aside from the north pole, you'll see seasonal fluctuations of sea level (the south pole melting more water than the north on average). That's coastal erosion. How much depends too much on the nature of each coast. Over those same geological periods it might mean a few more eroded feet here and there... except... those fluctuations might lead to some nasty storm patterns. Wind+water really erodes things. But that means looking at average hurricane/typhoon landfall and expecting greater erosion (both coastal and inland) there. You'd also see greater rainfall half the year as Antarctica contributes, but all in all that might mean no appreciable difference as the average rainfall over ten years might not be any different than on Earth today.

Then there's the north pole. That's where you might see the most erosion. That constantly cycling ice over northern Canada, Russia and Greenland just might seriously smooth things out. When something large like a sheet of ice melts, it moves. That movement is in many ways as bad as wind+water.


Conclusion: Earth
On Earth... and generalizing something awful (climate is whomping complex)... I would expect little to no change below the Tropic of Capricorn, some small increase between the tropics, and potentially a substantial increase in erosion above the Tropic of Cancer.
Conclusion: Generally
You haven't designed your planet yet. I said climate is complex! Climate questions are among the most difficult we answer because there are so many variables. How much land? What constitutes the land? What's the topography? How much rainfall? Are there rain shadows? And that's just a patch of land.... So, basic rules:

On a water world there would be no change in sea level year-to-year. The ice caps would grow and shrink at the same rate.

land gets colder than water. Where there's land you'll have significantly deeper ice caps. While a deeper ice cap leads to a larger reservoir of cold, the truth is that sunlight melts ice at a very consistent rate. Therefore, there's more ice to melt where there's land beneath, leading to greater run-off over that land.

The greater the disparity of land between the poles, the greater the biannual change in sea level.

The placement and size of the land under the ice cap will have a lot to do with whether or not that land, itself, is eroded.

Finally, thanks to the nearly infinite combinations of shape and type and constituency, etc., it's next to impossible to reasonably predict substantial equatorial erosion. Just remember, silt erodes more than clay, which erodes more than granite and the sharper the incline the faster the erosion... kinda... because those thousands of equations make predicting tomorrow's weather hard, much less practical erosion.

My thanks to @gs for pointing out that while glacial erosion can be powerful, it has also produced some of the most beautiful landscape on Earth. @GS rightly points to the Matterhorn. It's worth noting that mountains erode by getting shorter late in their history (generally). Early in their history they're getting skinnier as the downhill erosion takes the least off the top and the bottom erosion stays at the bottom. It's worth adding to @gs' comment that glacial erosion tends to make wide U-shaped valleys vs. water that tends to make narrow V-shaped valleys.


Good luck!

I'd add that just because you have a lot of glacial erosion doesn't mean you have to have a boring landscape. On average glacial erosion lowers the high points and fills in the low points, but in the process it has made some of the most breathtaking landmarks on Earth, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matterhorn

On a water world, I would expect no seasonal variation in sea level at all. As long as ice is floating in water, it is displacing its own weight in water. When it melts, it fills that volume exactly. Your mileage may vary for saltwater ocean and brackish ice, as it would be made of frozen sea ice and accumulated freshwater snow. I would not expect that to be a large difference.

@JoelHarmon What you would get is a substantial set of currents. The freeze-melt cycle on the two ends of the world would act like pistons in an engine. Variations of the sea floor would dictate how that world-current would set up.
